# Check if column values are increasing

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I got an Excel sheet like:

```
A     B       C
1     L11     6
1     L21    10
1     L31    20
2     L12     5
2     L22    15
2     L32    23
```

I want to make a formula to check if each consecutive 3 values in column C are increasing. How can I do it?

I've tried to group by, but was in vain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the value `6` is in `C1`, then you could put the following formula in `D3`: `=AND(C3>C2, C2>C1)`

Copy it down. If it's `TRUE`, it means that each consecutive 3 values in column `C` are increasing.

[image]

Comment: i want it for the whole sheet not just first three

Comment: But in your question you said "consecutive 3 values"

Comment: "Each" consecutive 3 values

Comment: Copy the formula down, then you will have it for the whole column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to quantify the trend here I am using a simple formula to calculate the slope for the 3 numbers using the values in y axis.

Formula

> =SLOPE(N2:N4,{1;2;3})

[image]